# Phonegap using Coldfusion as a backend to retrieve data

Tags: xcode, cordova, coldfusion

I am trying to develop a phonegap app that will call to my coldfusion server and return data to the phone app. I have seen a couple of tutorials that do not explain the code on the server side(the .cfc file). Like this one...
http://blog.ryanvikander.com/index.cfm/2012/3/28/Returning-Dynamic-Content-In-A-PhoneGap-App

I was hoping someone could provide some sample code of what the .cfc on my server would look like when it is receiving the request for data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's the example code from that link:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, width=device-width" />
        <title>My App</title>
        <script src="phonegap.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url:"http://www.ryanvikander.com/test.cfc?method=getdata",
                    success: function(data){
                        var content = $("#content");

                        content.html(data);
                    },
                    error: function(e){
                        console.log(e);
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="title_bar">Test</div>
        This is a test
        <div id="content"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The url `http://www.ryanvikander.com/test.cfc?method=getdata` doesn't have to be anything more than this:

```
<cfcomponent>

    <cffunction name="getdata" access="remote" output="false">

        <cfreturn "Hello World!" />

    </cffunction>


</cfcomponent>
```

Here, the `success` callback function will put the string `"Hello World!"` into `<div id="content"></div>`

If the function `renderdata()` returned a query, you could pass the querystring parameters `returnformat=json` and optionally `queryFormat=column` to have ColdFusion convert the query data into JSON. If the returned data is formatted in JSON, then you could iterate over that data to render HTML as in any website.

Comment: Thanks! Once I changed "access="public"" to "access="remote"" it worked. Now I can go from there.

Comment: Whoops! Fixed the access value.